# Nexus 5 won't connect to PC

Tags: usb-drivers, nexus-5

I have a Nexus 5. It is fairly new - I bought it about 2 weeks ago.

I have previously plugged it into my Windows 7 PC and been able to access the files on it.

However, today when I plugged it in, the PC couldn't find it. Some googling and investigation found that the device driver wasn't installed - and then it said that it didn't exist.

I have downloaded the Google USB Driver from the [official site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html). But when I told it to update/install this driver, I was told the driver didn't exist.

The [LG Driver](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/nexus-5-driver-adb-fastboot-installation-guide/) installed, but the PC still doesn't "see" the phone to let me use it as a USB.

I don't want a complicated solution. I just want to be able to get my photos off my phone and onto my computer.

Comment: The LG driver installed, but the PC still doesn't "see" the phone to let me use it as a USB.

Comment: LG driver found here: http://www.theandroidsoul.com/nexus-5-driver-adb-fastboot-installation-guide/

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25327339/1577396). This solved my issue :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1:**

1. Go to device manager in Windows and delete anything having to do with your phone (LG, Google, Android etc)
2. Plug in your phone, the drivers should install automatically

**Option 2:** 
Download [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) on your phone....you can transfer files over WiFi

Comment: Device Manager doesn't show ANY phone-related drivers - I can't see anything called LG, Google or Android, despite knowing some of these MUST be installed. I suspect this may be part of the problem.

Comment: Went with the Airdroid option. Thank you, it let me get the photos I was after.

Comment: My Nexus 5 was under "Other Devices". I right clicked on it, hit "Uninstall" and then reconnected my phone and it detected it.

Comment: My Nexus 5 was listed as "Asus Device" in its own category.

Comment: To me it was listed as "Acer Device" in its own category. [Windows 8].

Comment: The solution given in the below link helped me to resolve the issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/25417236/185758

If the problem persists, right-click the ACER ADB Interface and select 'Update driver...', then 'Browse my computer...' then 'Let me pick from a list...' and you should see two options for the Nexus, Google Nexus ADB Interface and another called MTP USB Device. Choose MTP and hit 'Next' to install the driver, then it should show up as a portable device on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

go to settings 
then storage 
click the 3 dots in the top right hand corner 
click USB computer connection
choose one of the 2 options

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted.  The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this answer worked great!

Comment: Agreed. The accepted answer did not work for me either, and furthermore, I would never advise someone to delete drivers that they can't even properly identify... all I had to do was swap from Media Device to Camera, and back again, though I suspect disabling Media Device and re-enabling it would have worked just as well. Then again, the OP only wanted to xfer files, so I guess the Airdroid solution was enough for s/he.